# TradingView. Pine-Script: Plotshape, using location.absolute and a boolean condition at the same time..?

Tags: pine-script

In the TradingView PineScript programming language, the Plotshape command format is:
plotshape(series, title, style, location, ....
Where "Series is treated as a series of boolean values for all location values except location.absolute. "

So with 'series' you can specify whether a shape has to be plotted or not, for a specific bar.
Except .... when you are using 'location.absolute'. In that case, the 'series' parameter is the vertical coordinate of the shape ... Weird syntax if you ask me. Why not add the coordinate as a separate parameter?

So, I can not use a boolean (to indicate whether a shape must be plotted or not) and an absolute location at the same time, in a single PlotShape command.
So, instead, I am using a boolean for 'series' and 'location.top' or 'location.bottom' instead. But this is not really what I want.

Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use a ternary so that you only plot the series when the boolean is true, and `na` when it isn't:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
ma = sma(close, 20)
xUp = crossover(close, ma)
plot(ma)
plotshape(xUp ? high + tr / 2 : na, "xUp", shape.cross, location = location.absolute, size = size.small)
```

[image]

Comment: Splendid! This is what I was looking for!
Thank you very much for this solution!


PS. Sorry for my late reply!

Comment: Happy this is easily findable on google, but maybe it's helpful to add to the language reference as well.

Comment: What's `tr` doing there?

Comment: It's true range and used to distance the plot from the `high`. It's not ideal because it varies, but it will often perform better on various types of charts than a fixed percentage.